# Busted subtitle synchronization

Tags: 14.04, vlc

I have a strange issue with VLC media player.
Every time I open a video with it the "Subtitle track synchronization" is automatically set to 11,000 seconds, as you can see from the picture below.
[image].

Is there any way to correct this strange behavior? Obviously, I'm searching for a more elegant way than a "purge --remove"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found an answer by myself searching for "11" pattern inside vlc settings files.
For others with same problem, the folder `~/.config/vlc` contains all vlc settings file (actually, I have two files on my system named `vlcrc` and `vlc-qt-interface.conf`).
Open `vlcrc` file with a text editor, search for `sub-delay` line and set it to 0 (i.e. `sub-delay=0`)